# how to install ZipArchive in the PHP Docker Container

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, php-7

in my laravel project I have this error

```
Class 'ZipArchive' not found
```

I need to install php-zip into my php container

I've changed the Dockerfile as I found some answers on the internet and added `extension=zip.so` to php.ini but it doesn't work.